# How to use blow-up to prove the boundary regularity for a harmonic function

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, blow-ups, harmonic-functions

While reading the book *Regularity Theory of Elliptic PDE* I’m confused with a theorem:

Thm. 2.30.

Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $k \in N$ with $k \leq 2$, and let $\Omega$ be a bounded $C^{k, \alpha}$ domain of $R^n$. Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ be a weak solution to

$$ \Delta u = f \hspace{2pt} \in \hspace{2pt}  \Omega $$
$$ u=g \hspace{2pt} \text{ on } \hspace{2pt} \partial \Omega$$

for some $f\in C^{k-2, \alpha}(\bar{\Omega}), g\in C^{k, \alpha}(\partial\Omega)$.

Then, $ u \in C^{k, \alpha}(\bar{\Omega})$ and

$$ \|u\|_{C^{k, \alpha}(\Omega)} \leq C(\|f\|_{C^{k-2, \alpha}(\Omega)}+\|g\|_{C^{k, \alpha}(\partial \Omega)})$$

Where C depending only on $\alpha, n, k \text{ and } \omega$.

The book didn’t give the proof but it says that it can be shown by techniques like:

after a blow-up, points near the boundary behave like in a local problem in the half-space (that is, the blow-up flattens ∂Ω), and we can reach a contradiction with Liouville’s theorem in the half-space.

But I fell into trouble at first because I don’t know how to do the blow-up to get the harmonic function in the half space. I tried to do it starting from that g is identically 0 and try to prove it for a $C^{k, \alpha}$ boundary, but if I set $u_r(x)=\frac{1}{r^2}u(rx)$ then I can’t even bound $D^k(u_r)$. What should I do to get the blow-up? Is there any reference I can send to?

Comment: I recall seeing a paper (and he also had some notes)  of Leon Simon from 90's  that had a proof using blow up analysis.

Comment: You can have a look at Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE by Xavier Fernandez-Real
and Xavier Ros-Oton (you can download it). In Chapter 2, the second proof of Proposition 2.25 they explain well the blow-up method in the case of interior points

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much for this reference but I’m still confused with a tricky problem: on the boundary condition we also assumed the boundary to be $C^{k, \alpha}$ and where would this assumption be used? I’m thinking that there may be some transform wish can remain the bound of the norm of C^{k, \alpha}$ but I can’t write it down clearly.

Comment: Assme $k=2$. You can change coordinates from $\Omega$ to the half plane using the smoothness of the boundary. Then you get another ellipitc equation in the half-plane with Holder coefficients. This is the way how the smoothness of the boundary is generally used. I do not know if the authors had that in mind.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I think you are right. But when I’m trying to write it down I’m faced with another problem: all the blow-up trick are based on one assumption—the solution is $C^{k, \alpha}$, which allows to consider $u-p$ where $p$ is a polynomial determined by the k-th derivative. And we would use the continuity method to determine the uniqueness of solution and therefore all the estimate can be done.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune But here we only assume that $u\in H^1$ so we may need to do it by Green function and all the techniques we talked above should be used for the general equation by the method of continuity

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that the book I recommended is exactly that you are reading (you did not write the authors and I got confused). I agree, the argument needs smooth functions and, in principle, is an a-priori estimates. However, having it, it can be used on a single equation, via approximation. See the proof of corollary 2.16 (in the edition I have), where the estimates are applied to mollifications of the weak solution..

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune The mollification may not be used near the boundary. But I’ve just reviewed the proof of cor. 2.16 and I think maybe we can use the mollification inside to get that the solution is $C^{k, \alpha}$ in any subset and therefore in $\Omega$. So we can use the a-priori estimate.

Comment: In my experience, it is easier to prove Schauder estimates for the Laplacian (or $D_t-\Delta$) in the whole space by blow-up and then use standard methods for variable coefficients and local estimates. If you look at the web, there is a short class note by R. Halshofer yielding Schauder estimates for $\Delta$ and the method generalizes to $D_t-\Delta$. Concerning boundary estimates, it is easier to go to the half space by local coodinates, to reduce to a homogenuous boundary value problem (by subtracting an extension of the boundary value) and to reflect to go to the whole space.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune Thank you very much for your help. I’m gonna try to do it in this method and I believe this is the right way.

Comment: @user734979 I am reading the same book too, and I still feel confused about the statement on the book. How can I use the priori estimates on it and how can I deal with the boundary value?

Comment: @RegaurCarchern Well,  I’m kind of confused about what you are saying. Do you mean you’ve already get the apriori estimate and you don’t know how to derive the regularity on the boundary?

Comment: @user734979, I mean that I cannot get the priori estimates by using the blow up method and also have trouble in showing that the weak solution is in $ C^{k+2} $.

Comment: @RegaurCarchern For the first one, I think you may be confused about the covering gap. At the boundary we may not get the covering by small balls. But, as I remember, you can get a similar covering lemma leave the interior part for the interior estimate. For the second one, I think you can use a sequence smooth functions tending to the given condition in the C^{k} norm and you got the estimate for the solution. With the uniqueness of solution you can show that the weak solution is C^{k+2}

Comment: @user734979, Thank you very much.

Comment: @RegaurCarchern You are welcome.